# PHP: Adding dynamic rows with multiple fields including checkboxes and submitting

Tags: php, html

I asked this before, maybe I am more clear this time. I have this form in input.php

[image]

The code for this table is

```
<div class="col-md-5 sec-col02">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Medicine Record</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                                    <div class="table-responsive">  
                                        <table style="margin-left:4px; margin-top:4px;" class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  <tr id="medicen">  
                                                <td>Medicine Name</td> 
                                                <td>Hours</td>
                                                <td>M</td>
                                                <td>E</td>
                                                <td>N</td>
                                                <td>No Of Days</td> 
                                                <td>Add</td>  
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>  
                                                <td><input style="width:95px; " type="text" name="medname[]" placeholder="Medicine Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td> 
                                                <td><select style="width:70px;" name="frequency[]" class="form-control name_list">
                                                <option value="24hours"> 24Hrs</option>
                                                <option value="8hrs"> 8Hrs</option>
                                                <option value = "12hrs">12Hrs</option></select></td>
                                                <td><input style="width:15px; " name="morning1" type ="checkbox" value="M" class = "form-control name_list"/></td>
                                                <td><input style="width:15px;" name="evening1" type ="checkbox" value="E" class = "form-control name_list"/></td>
                                                <td><input style="width:15px;" name="night1" value="N" type ="checkbox" class = "form-control name_list"/></td>
                                                <td><input style="width:80px;" type="text" name="days[]" placeholder="No Of Days" class="form-control name_list"/></td>
                                                <td><button style="width:13dx;" type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td>  
                                            </tr>  
                                        </table>  
                                    </div>  
                                </form>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And I am adding new rows like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
           var i=1;  
           $('#add').click(function(){  
              i++;  
              $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input style="width:95px; " type="text" name="medname[]" placeholder="Medicine Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><select style="width:70px;" name="frequency[]" class="form-control name_list"><option value="24hours"> 24Hrs</option><option value="8hrs"> 8Hrs</option><option value = "12hrs">12Hrs</option></select></td><td><input style="width:15px; " name="morning'+i+'" type ="checkbox" value="M" class = "form-control name_list"/></td><td><input style="width:15px;" name="evening'+i+'" type ="checkbox" value="E" class = "form-control name_list"/></td><td><input style="width:15px;"name="night'+i+'" value="N" type ="checkbox" class = "form-control name_list"/></td><td><input style="width:80px;"type="text" name="days[]" placeholder="No Of Days" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><button style="width:50px;"type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>'); 

           });
```

User adds inputs, may check a check box or not, and then click submit. There can be any number of rows. 
I have added this line `$('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');` to ensure check boxes are unchecked.

In getdata.php, when I try this code

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['medname']); $i++){
    $medName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['medname'][$i]);
    $medFreq = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['frequency'][$i]);
    $medMorning = '';
    if(isset($_POST['morning'.$i])){
        $medMorning = $_POST['morning'.$i];
    }
    print_r($medName);
    echo '<br/>'; 
    print_r($medFreq);
    echo '<br/>';
    print_r($medMorning);
    echo '<br/>';


}
echo $i." rows added";
```

all names and related frequencies are properly printed out. But when I try to get the check box related data, the result is:

A
8hrs

B
24hours
M
2 rows added
For this instance, In first row first check box (M) was checked. In second it wasnt checked.Result is giving M in any case.
How am I suppose to get all the right values in each row whether checked or not?

Thank you.

Comment: how many check boxes can be checked per row ?

Comment: Any combination. There is no restriction. Minimum is one.

Comment: is the table in a loop because i see you using name="morning[]" instead of name="morning"?

Comment: I am looping on the first field.."medname". Because it is going to be filled every time.  I have edited the table code. See my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
You are using the `name[]` notation to get arrays filled with the form values in `$POST`. This would work if you only had text inputs. However with checkboxes you have the problem that there will be no value added if you don't check the box.

For your use case a better solution would be to define individual input names for every added row:

```
<td><input name="morning-0" type ="checkbox" value="M" /></td>
...
<td><input name="morning-1" type ="checkbox" value="M" /></td>
...
<td><input name="morning-2" type ="checkbox" value="M" /></td>
```

Then you read the values dynamically in PHP:

```
$medMorning = '';
if(isset($_POST['morning-' . $i])){
    $medMorning = $_POST['morning-' . $i];
}
```

I quess you need some added JavaScript to generate the individual input names but it's not too much of a hassle.

Comment: Used your code. Checked the checkbox in the first row and left it blank in the second row. Result is "A 24hours M B 12hrs M 2 rows added. Why is M in both cases?

Comment: Can you post the whole `for` loop?

Comment: Ah, I get it! The problem is that you only set `$medMorning` when it is set in `$POST`. The second time it is not set in `$POST` so `$medMorning` keeps the value from the previous iteration. Write `$medMorning = '';` before the `if` block and you're fine. :)

Comment: yes he is right if the loop like that ,t will keep the value

Comment: Makes sense..But after adding 2 rows, the result is "A 24hours M, B 8hrs" 2 rows added. But for the first row , M wasnt checked. For B it was checked.

Comment: Can you debug print the whole `$POST` array and post it here?

Comment: print_r($_POST) will bring in all the fields posted in pages, are you sure? those are all simple text fields.

Comment: I think I get your problem now. The use of square brackets in the input names won't work for your use case as you (and I, initially) expected. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You mean in the input fields, remove the [] from all fields?

Comment: no but you need to change the html code a bit, you need to make a variable for the name then loop in you table loop make the name = the variable then check if that line was posted , the post arrays will be messed up because not every box is clicked

Comment: @BenjaminKrupp I have added the JS code. However, if I follow your suggestion, how will the table look like? same with 3 checkboxes?

Comment: @BenjaminKrupp I have updated the code. I am unsure whether to remove [] from textboxes too? I haven't removed from text fields as you can see from the code.

Comment: Looks good. You can leave the text boxes since they will just add empty strings to the post when left empty. So the array will always have the correct length. Does everything work now? :)

Comment: Oh, wait. You have to make sure that the indices match. Start e.g. with `morning0` and `var i=0`.

Comment: In JS and PHP for loop?

Comment: Yeah. For example if there are two entries: medname = `array(0 => 'first med', 1 => 'second med')` you want to have the same index for your `morning` fields => `array('morning0' => 'M', 'morning1' => '')`.

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks. Now let me try with all check boxes :)

Comment: Happy to hear it! :)